# Visual Studio: Shortcut/way to add new class with namespace and auto create folder (and put it there)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In IntelliJ, I can create a new class and if I name it `com.mystuff.db.DbLoader`, then it auto-creates the following directories and file:

```
com
   /mystuff
      /db
         /DbLoader.java
```

Is there a shortcut for doing the same in Visual Studio for a C# class?

Comment: In VS, each project has its own default namespace and when you add a class via the GUI the new class starts off with that name space. Same thing for the directory in which the project is located. The new class will have that directory as its parent. But that's about it. New classes start off with what the project has.

Comment: @Displayname yes, I know. But I want to make a class that's in `/<project_root>/Database/DbLoader.cs`. From what I can tell, that takes a lot of unecessary clicks to first create the folder, then create the file in that folder.